# PID Vs PID (2 DOF)

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'll like to know the difference between the PID and PID (2 DOF) blocks in Simulink. Also, I am trying to track a steady state value of a signal that changes every 5 seconds, which of these blocks can help me stabilize the system before the next steady state signals come.

Answer (score 1):

The [PID Controller (2 DOF)](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller2dof.html) implements setpoint weighting in the controller, which the normal [PID Controller](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller.html) block does not. It's difficult to answer your question without knowing more about the problem, however the standard PID block is good enough in a large proportion of control problems, so I would try this first. If you find the performance is not satisfactory, you can then try the PID Controller (2 DOF) block.

Comment: Thanks am304,however, I have read of the setpoint weighing capability of the PID(2DOF) but I do not understand the technical term of "set Point weighing and the signal tracking thing", or how does it really work?
Once again, Thanks

Comment: The mathematical details of how it works are detailed in the documentation. The best thing is to try it out really.